# Constraintlayout(in RelativeLayout) layout_alignParentBottom cuts from bottom(in default mode of app)

Tags: android, android-layout, android-constraintlayout, android-relativelayout

I have added `ConstraintLayout` in `RelativeLayout` and I want that at the bottom of my `RelativeLayout`.So, it's proper when the app opens in full-screen mode but in default mode `ConstraintLayout` cuts from the bottom.

I have checked this thing in the different scenario like if I put it on top it comes proper even in the default mode but when I align it to bottom it gets cut.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/cameraView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="org.cocos2dx.cpp.AppActivity">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/control"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="112dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="@color/control_background"
        android:paddingBottom="0dp">

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/cancelBtn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:src="@drawable/close"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageCaptureBtn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:scaleX="1.20"
            android:scaleY="1.20"
            android:src="@drawable/capture"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.5" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/reverseCameraBtn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|right"
            android:layout_marginEnd="30dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:src="@drawable/reverse_cam"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.508" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

So, here in `ConstraintLayout` when I keep `android:layout_alignParentTop="true"` It doesn't get cut from top like in the image

[image]

but when I give it to `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"` it gets cut only in default mode of the app and I want this `ConstraintLayout` at bottom of the `RelativeLayout`

[image]

Comment: why you want to use rootlayout as relativelayout?

Comment: Try to give `fillViewPort` true in `RelativeLayout`

Comment: by setting fillViewPort true is also not working

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `ConstraintLayout` as a Root view like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/cameraView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/control"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="112dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/cancelBtn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_attach"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageCaptureBtn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:scaleX="1.20"
            android:scaleY="1.20"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_attach"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/reverseCameraBtn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|right"
            android:layout_marginEnd="30dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_attach"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            tools:ignore="RtlHardcoded" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: It's still giving the same output.
FYI: I have tested it on Xiomi Redmi 5
Note: It's working properly in Fullscreen mode but when I switch to default mode it's giving me the weird output